# UWP appx sideloading issue

Tags: uwp, appx, sideloading

We are facing a issue in sideloading app in our production environment. we have signed the app with enterprise trusted certificate. on each user login we run the script to install the appx. but for some users we are getting a error like below
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFF, To install this application you
need either a Windows developer license or a sideloading-enabled system.
Deployment of package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe with package origin
Unsigned failed because no valid license or sideloading policy could be applied. A developer
license (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=233074) or enterprise sideloading configuration
(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231020) may be required.
the min target version of appx : 10586
max version : 17134
could you help us here ?

Comment: Have you tried enabling Settings->Update&Security->For Developers -> Developer Mode ?

Comment: Actually for development it works fine i have enabled the developer mode settings.The issue is happening with while installing on production machines, eventhough we have copied the enterprise certificate  it still give the error

Comment: You have to enable SideLoad Mode in production machines too.

Comment: We have enabled sideload mode in production , this issue is happening after enabling sideload mode in production

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ?